# iOS dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier is always returning null

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm really frustrated at this point. Dequeueing a reusable cell with identifier is always returning null.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil) {
        NSLog(@"INIT");
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

What am i doing wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: How many rows did your tableView have when you tested that it always returned null?

Comment: There's only 1 section and `numberOfRowsInSection` returns 5. The console is outputting "INIT" 5 times :(

Comment: Cells are only reused if a row becomes invisible due to scrolling. The cell is then reused for a different (now visible) row. If you have only 5 rows this probably will never happen. Where is the problem?

Comment: @AlexTaylor: I assume that you had this in mind when you were asking about the number of rows. Perhaps you want to post an answer.

Comment: Definitely, you got it @MartinR

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're doing everything right, everything is working as it should. iOS will create enough new cells to fill the screen (plus one). It will start reusing these cells only when your `UITableView` contains more rows than can fit on one screen and then the user scrolls.

You'll find that if you have a datasource will say, 100 items in it and then scroll, you'll only have your log message show probably 11 times (depends on how many cells fit on your screen) instead of 100 as iOS will start recycling cells as you scroll.

With large lists, it would use too much memory to create new views for every possible row in a `UITableView`. The alternative would be to allocate new views for rows as you scroll. However, this would create a performance bottleneck that would cause laggy scrolling in any `UITableView`.

Apple mention the performance bottleneck [in their documentation on `UITableView`s](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1).

> Reuse cells. - Object allocation has a performance cost, especially if the allocation has to happen repeatedly over a short period—say, when the user scrolls a table view. If you reuse cells instead of allocating new ones, you greatly enhance table view performance.

Comment: Thanks Alex! Just tested your theory and you are correct. I had the assumption that with a datasource as small as 5; the output in my console will display "INIT" once and reuse the same cell 4 more times.

Comment: Great work. The main purpose of the cell reuse is to provide a performance boost without sacrificing much memory.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set your cell's reuse identifier? Init your cell with `-initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:`, or set the identifier in IB.

Comment: I'm not using IB and yes; i'm init my cell with `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:`.